# Django, get number of items from each author, return authors with most items

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have following models:

```
#models.py
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)

#author
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    picture = models.ImageField()
```

I want to find out which authors have the most posts and get the top 6 in the most optimum way possible.  I also want to get the picture from each author.

This is what I have, but I can't figure how to get the profile pic in the same query.  Can anyone help please?  Thanks,

```
authors = Blog.objects.values('author').annotate(posts=Count('author')).order_by('-posts')[:6]
```

Comment: I am not in front of my vagrant box right now, but does this work?
`blogs = Blog.objects.select_related('author').annotate(posts=Count('author')).order_by('-posts')[:6]`

Then in your template:
`for blog in blogs:
      blog.author.picture
`

Comment: Ah, that might work but i don't want to pass the blogger object to the template - just the important fields from it

Comment: then `.values('author__picture`)` does that work?

Comment: yep, just added to values.  was simple after all.  Thanks!  If you add as answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bellow queryset should do the job:

```
authors = Blog.objects.values('author__picture').annotate(posts=Count('author')).order_by('-posts')[:6]
```